# How to convert loops in Ruby to C#?

Tags: c#, ruby

Can u help me a litte bit? 
How does this code will look like in c#?

```
return Array.new(minmax.size) do |i|
    minmax[i][0] + ((minmax[i][1] - minmax[i][0]) * rand())
end
```

or this one (is this simple foreact loop?)

```
vector.each_with_index do |input, i|
    sum += weights[i] * input
end
```

Comment: What does the code do in Ruby?

Comment: Have you tried Googling "C# loops" or "Ruby loops" to research either method?

Comment: Was that "Ruby" code already translated to Ruby from another language? Looks like a very bad way to write `minmax.map { |min, max| min + (max - min) * rand }`.

Answer (score -2):

Using LINQ, you can convert these as follows:

```
var rand = new Random();
return Enumerable.Range(0, minmax.Length-1).Select(i => minmax[i][0]+((minmax[i][1] - minmax[i][0])*rand.NextDouble())).ToArray();
```

For the second one:

```
var sum = vector.Select((input, i) => new { input, i }).Aggregate(0, (s, input_i) => s+weights[input_i.i]*input_i.input);
```

Or perhaps:

```
var sum = vector.Zip(weights, (v,w) => v*w).Sum();
```

In C# however, looping is normally done with `for` or `foreach`:

```
var rand = new Random();
var res = new Array(minmax.Length);
for (var i = 0; i < minmax.Length; ++i)
    res[i] = minmax[i][0] + ((minmax[i][1] - minmax[i][0])*rand.GetDouble());
return res;
```

For the second:

```
for (var i = 0; i < vector.Length; ++i)
    sum += weights[i] * vector[i];
```